# Is it possible to process-redirect to source?

Tags: shell-script, source

I want to watch (and wait) for the processes spawned by a command, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663196/how-to-wait-on-all-child-and-grandchild-etc-process-spawned-by-a-script/18663969#18663969) which seems pretty much exactly what I need. Except that I want the script to be self-contained, so instead of sourcing a file, can I use process redirection to create it on the fly?? e.g;

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tasklist="(
  command1
  if abc; then
    command2
  elif
    command3
  fi
  command4
)"
source < <(echo "$tasklist") ; wait
```

I tested it with `cat` and later with `bash` and it worked:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tasklist="(
  echo "command1"
  echo "command2"
  echo "command3"
)"
bash < <(echo "$tasklist")
```

I can't bring myself to do it with `source` though. I had some bad experiences with it before. :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works, in Bash 4.4 and above anyway, this prints `hi` and `hello`:

```
cmds='echo hi; var=hello'
source <(echo "$cmds") 
echo $var
```

You need `source <(...)`, not `source < <(...)` as `source` takes a filename which the process substitution already provides. No need for the redirection.

Though, if you have those commands in a variable, you could just run  `eval "$cmds"` instead. Or if the commands are fixed, just run them directly without bothering with the intermediate variable, i.e.

```
echo hi; var=hello
echo $var
```

Anyway, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to `wait` for there. `wait` waits for background jobs and you don't have any there. All those regular commands started without `&` run in the foreground, and the shell will wait for them anyway before reading any new commands.